# How to use session tokens correctly?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using the Java client for the Google Places API:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The following is how I use the autocomplete API on my server:

```java
public List<AutocompletePrediction> searchAddress(String query) {

    List<AutocompletePrediction> predictions = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        AutocompletePrediction[] autocompletePredictions = PlacesApi
                .placeAutocomplete(geoApiContext, query, null) 

        predictions.addAll(Arrays.asList(autocompletePredictions));
    } catch (ApiException | InterruptedException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return predictions;
}
```

Now, at the time I am passing `null` as the `sessionToken`:

```
.placeAutocomplete(geoApiContext, query, null)
```

mainly because I am not entirely sure how these are supposed to work.

I could create *one* token every 2 minutes and use that token no matter which user is currently typing.

So this would mean if two users search for "location" and "place", the incoming queries might look like this:

```
[User 1] 1. lo
[User 2] 2. p
[User 1] 3. loca
[User 2] 4. plac
[User 1] 5. locat
[User 1] 6. location
[User 2] 7. place
```

now, I could use for all those requests the same token `X` and create a new one every one or two minutes but I don't know whether this is allowed and whether this affects billing.

The other way would be to create a cache per user which stores for user `1` and `2` a token `X1` and `X2` respectively. This solution would be a little more complex which is why I'd like to know whether the first solution would already work in the sense of I won't get billed for every single request.

#### Documentation

- [Session Tokens](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/session-tokens)
- [Autocomplete Sesssions](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#about-autocomplete-sessions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using session tokens because they do affect billing. According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#session_tokens):

> If the `sessiontoken` parameter is omitted, or if you reuse a session
>   token, the session is charged as if no session token was provided.

Example of request that uses a sessiontoken:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=1600+Amphitheatre&key=<API_KEY>&sessiontoken=1234567890
```

Please create a new and unique session token for each Autocomplete session as suggested in the linked documentation.

To further clarify on sessions:

> A session token is good for **one** user session and should not be used
>   for more than one user session.

A session begins when the user starts typing a query, and concludes when they select a place (i.e. when a [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) call is made). This is billed on the [Autocomplete (included with Places Details) – Per Session SKU](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#ac-with-details-session).

If this one user does *not* make a selection, the session will end after a short time out period (i.e. within a few minutes of the beginning of the session). This is billed on the [Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session SKU](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#ac-no-details-session).

If you do not use a session token or it is deemed invalid, you will be billed on the [Autocomplete – Per Request SKU](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#ac-per-character).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not clear to me what a "session" defines. This does not really answer my question, sorry.

Comment: My apologies, please see my edit above for clarification.

Comment: So, what I need is how this would look like in my `searchAddress()` which is a server-side service method. It's not clear to me how to manage sessions on my server it's also not clear what happens in a concurrent setup as stated in my question. Your answer consists currently only of quotes of the documentation, but it's the documentation I do not understand.

Comment: I'm sorry but why can't you create a token to replace the null you currently pass into your method, and generate a new one when done? Sorry I must not understand your issue.

Comment: My question contains an example of two users typing "*location*" and "*place*" at the same time into an input box. All their requests are handled on my server so my server has to generate a session token. The question is whether those two users can share either one or two session tokens. In any case, my server has to cache the token(s) for an unknown amount of time. It is not clear how the Autocomplete API should be used server side w.r.t. session tokens.

Comment: You can only use one session token per user. Not two or more. Two users can't share the same session token. The linked documentation states: "A session token is good for one user session and should not be used for more than one user session. If you reuse a session token, the session is considered invalid and the requests are charged as if no session token was provided.". I hope this answers your concern but please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Well, the question is: "How would Google know?" I can just create *one* token every 2 minutes and use this single token for 100 users. How would Google know? I know what the docs say but it's not really clear what prevents me to just send all requests in a two minute time window using just one session token. I say two minutes but I don't know how long a token is valid since it's also not stated in the docs.

Comment: Or am I not seeing something here? ^^

Comment: Google would know because your app would be making two (or more) calls to their API with the same session token. Note that each session ends once a Places Details call is made. So if "Token A" is used in two Autocomplete queries (e.g. "Paris,France" and "Berlin,Germany"), these count as 2 different Autocomplete sessions that use the same session token hence Google will know and consider the second session invalid. Please read carefully the example in https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/session-tokens#example

Comment: But I will never make a Place Details call. I only use the Autocomplete endpoint in order to present places. And even if so. I can still make 1000 requests with the same token and all I have to do is one Place Details calls in order to get billed only for one request. One piece of the puzzle is simply missing here ..

Comment: Btw the docs also state "*If the user does not make a selection, the session will end after a short time out period.*" - but Google does not know about a user. Google only sees a token.

Comment: As stated above and in the docs - place selection or short time out ends an autocomplete session. I'm on mobile sorry will elaborate later but please do read the docs as they are quite clear on this. It's no puzzle. Use one unique session token per autocomplete session per user or you will be billed per request and there's no way to trick Google on this.

Comment: Just for the record, I do not intend to trick Google. I just want to do it right. But could answer this question: Let's assume a token is valid for 5 minutes. Let's assume I have 10 users during that 5 minutes which use my implementation of autocomplete. Now, `searchAddress()` from above will receive a new token every 4:59 minutes. So .. I create `Token_1` and use that for 5 minutes. My 10 users make requests. After 5 minutes I generate `Token_2` - and some other users use my website and make requests. Based on the docs I have to believe that all those requests will be grouped by those tokens.

Comment: The question: Why would the above not work based on what we know from the docs?

Comment: It would not work because that's not the documented way to implement Autocomplete sessions; if all your users start making requests within those 5 minutes they will fail. You may not be trying to trick Google but it would look that way. The documentation clearly states "A session token is good for one user session and should not be used for more than one user session.". Hence in your app you should assign a unique session token for each of your end-users. This is the right and only way to use sessions. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: It seems we are not on the same page here. That's not really a reason for it to not work. E.g. the docs state "*Each session can have multiple queries, followed by one place selection.*" which means that I can technically do what I am suggesting. You are focusing too much on "users". Google does not see or know about users. It only sees my server talking to their API. In a wider sense, my server is the "user". Now the only question is: How longis a session token valid?

Comment: Listen, don't you think that if your interpretation of Google's documentation was correct, it would be in fact at the very least mentioned somewhere? And that this documentation wouldn't explicitly, repeatedly say you need to create a new session token for each user session or you'll be billed per request, no exceptions? For your own good you should implement sessions the way Google tells you to, your own opinions and interpretations aside. And look, even if Google never found out you're misusing the service, the only real question is why would you? I assume you're a good person so just don't?

Comment: This is actually just all about me being lazy. If I can use a token within a 2 minute time window, then I can create just *one* global token every two minutes on my server and call it a day. Having one token per user on the client side would be easy, but on the server side I need to manage a cache for that. I need to map some sort of user-id to the specific user-token unless I trust clients to "*do it right*". I'm really just looking for a simpler technical solution.

Comment: I understand that, but often the right way to do things isn't the easiest one. Personally I'd take hard work over risking getting extra billed or into legal trouble any day, but that's just me. Good luck whatever you do.

Comment: Alright. I will go the more complicated way of managing session tokens for multiple users. Definitely thanks for your patience and help on this :D

Comment: Hey you pleasantly surprised me there! :) Glad to hear you'll implement session tokens in the proper way. I'm sure you'll finish it sooner than you think.

Comment: I can be moved by arguments :D