# Prevent google places autocomplete to look up PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

We want to reduce our google api costs and are therefor reducing our api calls. Google automatically fires an api call when you use the autocomplete on our site, it does a PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails request. Are there ways to prevent this?

I'm using this to init the autocomplete

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { componentRestrictions: {country: country_code} });
autocomplete.setFields(['formatted_address']);
```

I use the .setFields as a temp solution to prevent google from looking up other costly data.

Comment: Your solution is the solution. By default, all fields are returned. You have to specify that you only want certain fields in order to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: @ecg8 Thank you for your reply. I only want to use the autocomplete to populate a search field, so I only want to see the text the visitor clicked on in the autocomplete. I don't care about the exact location data etc - I will get that serverside and match it with out database. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: You cannot use Autocomplete without at the same time calling Places Details, even if you don't call `getPlace()` after the user selects a place. You can only avoid getting charged for Places Details if users do not select a place, but that'd obviously not fulfill your requirements nor would it lower costs. Please check out this answer (and the linked docs) on how Autocomplete sessions are billed https://stackoverflow.com/a/57409080/11742502